# How to setup google enhanced ecommerce on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ecommerce-tracking, google-enhanced

How to setup **google enhanced ecommerce web tracking** code on magento 1.9

reference:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Comment: Can you please check this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/tatvic-tatvic-google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce.html